# Qt QImage->setPixel is going beyond the expected range

Tags: qt, qimage, qt4.8

I am trying to set the pixel colors based on the height.  I divided the screen into two parts and setting pixels based on the height if the height is less than
middle point pixel color is set to one color and greater values with different color. Problem is few of the pixels are set after the middle point with first half colors.
I am new to graphics Kindly suggest.  But with same calculation I am able to draw the line exactly at the middle.
My code:
int setImagePixcels(float &pX1,float &pY1,float &pX2,float &pY2)
{

```
int lValue = 0 ,pixelValY2=0, pixelValY1=0, pixelValX1=0, pixelValX2=0 ;
int width= 0, height=0 , maxY=0,maxX=0,startx=0,starty=0;
FILE *myFile=NULL;
QRgb rgblo; 

pixelValX1= vPlotXY->getPixelXFromValueX(pX1); //px1 is  x1
pixelValX2= vPlotXY->getPixelXFromValueX(pX2); // px2 is x2

startx = vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[LEFT]; //Starting point of x
starty = vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[TOP];  //starting point of y

pixelValY1= vPlotXY->getPixelYFromValueY(pY1);     //py1 is  y1
pixelValY2= vPlotXY->getPixelYFromValueY(pY2);     //py2 is  y2


width = (vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[RIGHT]-vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[LEFT]); //width of the screen
height =(vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[BOTTOM]-vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[TOP]); //height of the screen

float slope =(float) (pixelValY2-pixelValY1)/(pixelValX2-pixelValX1);


  myFile = fopen("C:\\MyLearning\\myData.txt","w+");
  if(!myFile)
  {
    //  cout<<"error"; failure.
  }

 //int dy = (pixelValY2-pixelValY1); // This the delta for y
 //int dx = (pixelValX2-pixelValX1); // This the delta for x
 maxY = vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[BOTTOM];
 maxX = vPlotXY->vAxisPositionInPixels[RIGHT];

 for(int y= starty;y<maxY;y++)
 {      
    for(int  x= startx;x<maxX;x++)
    {
        int midHeight = vPlotXY->getPixelYFromValueY(1500); 
        //float lineVal = (dy*x)-(dx*y)+(dx);
        //if((lineVal< 0)&& (axisVal[x-startx][y-starty]==0))
        if(y<midHeight)
        {
            vColor = 1;
        }
        else
        {

                vColor = 2;

        }

        //  axisVal[x-startx][y-starty]=vColor;


            switch(vColor)
            {
                case GridColor::CYAN:
                rgblo= qRgb(0,255,255);

                break;
                case GridColor::SPRINGGREEN:
                rgblo= qRgb(0   ,250,   154);
                break;
                case GridColor::GREEN:
                    rgblo= qRgb(0   ,205,   102);
                break;  

                case GridColor::DODERBLUE:
                    rgblo= qRgb(30  ,144    ,255);
                break;
                case GridColor::SGI_SALMON:
                    rgblo= qRgb(198,    113,    113);
                break;
                case GridColor::SGI_OLIVERDRAB:
                    rgblo= qRgb(142 ,142    ,56);
                break;
                case GridColor::SGI_LIGHTBLUE:
                break;
                case GridColor::MEDIUMORCHID:
                    rgblo= qRgb(186,85,211);
                break;
                case GridColor::YELLOW:
                    rgblo= qRgb(255,255,0);
                break;
                case GridColor::MEDIUMPURPLE:
                    rgblo= qRgb(147,    112,    219);
                break;
                default:
                    rgblo= qRgb(255 ,255,255);
                    break;

            }
                vImage->setPixel(x-75,y-89,rgblo);


        //fprintf(myFile, "(x=%d, y=%d)=(%d)", x,y,axisVal[x][y]);   
        //}
    }
    fprintf(myFile, "\n");
}
fclose(myFile);

return  lValue;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> few of the pixels are set after the middle point with first half
>   colors.

I will start to check the definition of the middle point. as your code below, I don't understand how this getPixelYfromValueY() function work. As the function name declared, it looks like to get the color value not the midHeight Y position, and You use it to compare at the for loop.  I believe this is problem.

```
int midHeight = vPlotXY->getPixelYFromValueY(1500);
```

Comment: getPixelValueFromY is the function returns the pixel value of the label 1500 in the graph or plot area. With the label value 1500(Y-axis scale, 3000 is max) ,10000(x-axis max). I used the function able to draw a line between (0,1500)(x1,y1) and (10000,1500)(x2,y2) exactly in the middle of the  plot area. But setpixel is going beyond the line.